# Return only specific tags with elemtree

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I am using elementree to parse an XML file with data taken from open maps into a new (shorter) file. I know the data is contained in "nodes" and "tags" with the tags having attributes. Some nodes have a tag with the addr:housenumber attribute. I am able to read from the current file and write the results to a new file using iterparse with the following code:

```
with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'wb') as output:
for i, element in enumerate(get_elements(OSM_FILE)):
    output.write(ET.tostring(element, encoding='utf-8'))
```

The get_elements function looks like this:

```
def is_house_num(elem):
    return (elem.attrib['k'] == "addr:housenumber")

    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag in tags:
            yield elem
            root.clear()
```

I am able to identify which nodes have the correct attribute tag using:

```
    for event, elem in context:
        if elem.tag == "node":
            for tag in elem.iter("tag"):
                if elem.attrib['k'] == "addr:housenumber":
```

But when I try to include the last block of code in my function, I am unable to make it so that the output in the first block of code is only nodes that contain a tag for the addr:housenumber attribute.

A sample of the file I'm trying to filter is:

```
  <node id="356681982" lat="40.3980061" lon="-111.8418770" version="1" timestamp="2009-03-07T14:13:58Z" changeset="749606" uid="4732" user="iandees">
    <tag k="amenity" v="school"/>
    <tag k="ele" v="1397"/>
    <tag k="gnis:county_id" v="049"/>
    <tag k="gnis:created" v="02/25/1989"/>
    <tag k="gnis:feature_id" v="1448986"/>
    <tag k="gnis:state_id" v="49"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Sego Lily School"/>
  </node>
  <node id="356682074" lat="40.2799548" lon="-111.6457549" version="2" timestamp="2014-08-11T20:33:35Z" changeset="24687880" uid="2253787" user="1000hikes">
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Provo"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="3570"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="84604"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Timpview Drive"/>
    <tag k="building" v="school"/>
    <tag k="ele" v="1463"/>
    <tag k="gnis:county_id" v="049"/>
    <tag k="gnis:created" v="02/25/1989"/>
    <tag k="gnis:feature_id" v="1449106"/>
    <tag k="gnis:state_id" v="49"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Timpview High School"/>
    <tag k="operator" v="Provo School District"/>
  </node>
  <node id="356682151" lat="40.2221771" lon="-111.6590893" version="1" timestamp="2009-03-07T14:14:14Z" changeset="749606" uid="4732" user="iandees">
    <tag k="amenity" v="school"/>
    <tag k="ele" v="1376"/>
    <tag k="gnis:county_id" v="049"/>
    <tag k="gnis:created" v="02/25/1989"/>
    <tag k="gnis:feature_id" v="1449138"/>
    <tag k="gnis:state_id" v="49"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Utah Valley Vocational School"/>
  </node>
```

In this case I would want the new file to contain only the middle node, like this:

```
<node id="356682074" lat="40.2799548" lon="-111.6457549" version="2" timestamp="2014-08-11T20:33:35Z" changeset="24687880" uid="2253787" user="1000hikes">
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Provo"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="3570"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="84604"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Timpview Drive"/>
    <tag k="building" v="school"/>
    <tag k="ele" v="1463"/>
    <tag k="gnis:county_id" v="049"/>
    <tag k="gnis:created" v="02/25/1989"/>
    <tag k="gnis:feature_id" v="1449106"/>
    <tag k="gnis:state_id" v="49"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Timpview High School"/>
    <tag k="operator" v="Provo School District"/>
  </node>
```

Comment: Can you use a library with xpath support (lxml, for example) instead of elementtree?

Comment: I could yes, I'm not familiar with any of the other libraries. After creating the new file I'll need to be able to manipulate the data and transform it into a JSON so I can create a MongoDB database from teh data so if there are other libraries that would make that easier I'm open to learning.

Comment: The output is xml, so whatever method you would have used to convert the middle node to json, you could use with lxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to get it to work by modifying my get_elements function (which apparently I forgot to include above) to read:

```
def get_elements(osm_file, tags = ('node', 'way')):
    context = iter(ET.iterparse(osm_file, events = ('start','end')))
    _, root = next(context)

    for event, elem in context:
        if elem.tag == "node" and event == 'end':
            for tag in elem.iter("tag"):
                if tag.attrib['k'] == "addr:housenumber":
                    yield elem
                    root.clear()
                else:
                    root.clear()
```